# Ruby: Using the unless keyword with a return statement

Tags: ruby

I am currently working on a project where I have code that looks like this:

```
  # the first return is the one causing problems
  def collect
    return Hash["IdentANode", Array[@id, ",", @ident_a_node.collect]] unless @ident_a_node.nil? and @id.nil?
    return Hash["IdentANode", @id] unless @id.nil?
  end
```

Where I use the unless operator to conditionally execute the return statement. For some reason this code *still* executes even if `@ident_a_node` is `nil`. When executing I get this message:

> IdentANode.rb:14:in `collect': undefined method`collect' for
>   nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Which confuses me because I had thought that the unless keyword would prevent this from happening. When I change the statement to this form:

```
if not @ident_a_node.nil? and not @id.nil?
  return Hash["IdentANode", Array[@id, ",", @ident_a_node.collect]]
end
```

or this form:

```
return Hash["IdentANode", Array[@id, ",", @ident_a_node.collect]] if not @ident_a_node.nil? and not @id.nil?
```

The return statement is *not* executed, what gives? Why is there a difference between these two statements? Does having multiple conditions with the `unless` keyword cause problems?

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a logic failure in there. You're testing that they're *both* `nil` to avoid running it when you should be testing if *either* is `nil`. You've probably gotten yourself into this situation by having too many layers of negation. Anything more than one is unacceptable.

In other words, you can get away with "if it's not raining out" but shouldn't use things like "unless the `is_not_raining` flag is not set to the inverse of false".

My personal opinion is that trailing conditions should not be used unless it's obvious that they're present. As you can see in your example, you have to scroll horizontally to find the condition, hiding important information from the developer.

As a matter of style, do not use `not` when `!` will do the same job. Secondly, you're testing specifically against `nil` when you probably just want a defined value of some kind.

Other issues include using `Hash[]` and `Array[]` which are surely artifacts of using a language which requires them. Ruby, like JavaScript, allows implicit declaration of these using `{ }` and `[ ]` respectively.

A proper Ruby-styled version of your code is:

```
if (@ident_a_node and @id)
  return { "IdentANode" => [ @id, ",", @ident_a_node.collect ] }
end
```

Comment: Why the `return`? I'd just do `if ...; [expr]; else; nil; end` (to make it clear that `nil` is returned in case of failure)

Comment: What I am doing in the collect method is returning a Hash, so if the value is nil, it should return the Hash with a nil value. `{ "IdentANode" => nil }`

Comment: The main reason I choose to use unless is because I have a lot of these conditionals and having an if statement for each would make the code messier in my opinion.

Comment: Also, is there a good style guide to refer to for things like the `Hash[]` and `Array[]` vs `{ key => value }` and `[]`??

Comment: @Hunter: Isn't it obvious that literals are cleaner than explicit constructors when available? As for general Ruby style, I like the [Github Ruby Guidelines](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby)

Comment: @NiklasB. The majority of my programming experience comes from Java and C, literals don't exist for these things in Java and C

Comment: @Hunter: Well, they do in most modern languages, like JavaScript, Python, LISP (Clojure, Scheme, CL, ...), Scala, Haskell, ... Actually C is very low-level, it has no built-in data structures except for arrays (for which the initialization syntax exists). The fact that Java doesn't have such a thing is a huge bummer, IMHO (but it also has the `new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }` thing).

Comment: @NiklasB. I agree the verbosity of languages like Java is a huge downside, but it is a hard transition for me everything I know about programming comes from that paradigm of verbosity

Comment: @Hunter: I think that's not too much of a problem. Most of these languages are based on one to three very basic data structures that are then used very extensively in every application. For Ruby those are arrays, hashes and maybe symbols (I didn't include strings here because you should be used to their syntax from Java). If you know how and when to use those, it'll be an easy transition :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use unless with and/or, it's just plain confusing. `unless @ident_a_node.nil? and @id.nil?` means `if !(@ident_a_node.nil? and @id.nil?)`, which means it will return whenever one of the two instance variables is not nil.

```
if !(@ident_a_node.nil? and @id.nil?)
```

is the same as

```
if !@ident_a_node.nil? or !@id.nil?
```

which should make it even clearer, why it is not the same as

```
if not @ident_a_node.nil? and not @id.nil?
```

Comment: for some reason I was expecting a translation like this: `if !first_condition and !second_condition` Thank you very much

Comment: @Hunter: When it comes to the negation of conjunction and disjunction, [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) are very helpful.

Comment: @NiklasB. Considering that the OPs kind of mistake is a very common one I would consider it confusing enough to avoid :) There is no reason why we should have to apply De Morgan in our head every time we see an unless with and/or. There's also no benefit to using unless here.

Comment: @dominik: `unless` allows you to express your conditions in plain English. Moreover, the `return unless` is an idiom that I see pretty often, so it strikes me that a lot of people are used to it. To be honest, I see those kinds of boolean errors very rarely from experienced developers, which is why I don't consider it confusing.

Comment: I tried using `unless` the way @NiklasB. advices, the same issue remains. `unless` is tricky.

Comment: @Yasky: I see what you mean. OP probably means `return unless @ident_a_node and @id`. No need to use `nil?` (I must have overread that). I consider this cleaner than the equivalent `return if @ident_a_node.nil? or @id.nil?`

Comment: Actually I think I like it most because it has the same semantics as an `assert`. Basically we can swap the `return unless` with `assert` or `raise ArgumentError, "..." unless` anytime.